# Certain character combinations are being replaced by 'undefined' in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: undefined, microsoft-edge, phpbb3

Certain character combinations are being rendered in the Microsoft Edge browser as 'undefined'. For example, in the link below, the teline of text:

I believe "Pilot" line is giving error message

is showing as:

I believe "Piloundefined line is giving error message

http://www.mychevybolt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=158

And on this page, the line of text:

The Bolt EV is being assembled at the General Motors Orion Assembly Plant in Township, Michigan.

is showing as:

The Bolt EV is being assembled at the General Motors Orion Assembly Plant in Townshundefined, Michigan.

http://www.mychevybolt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=162

There doesn't seem to be much rhyme or reason to when or why it happens. I've played with charset and can't seem to make it change.
It doesn't happen in any other browsers including IE11

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Microsoft Support, they gave me the basis 'clear the cache' line. And surprisingly it worked! The problem re-appears every week or so and then I clear the cache again and it's temporarily fixed.